# java.lang.StackOverflowError while converting BindingResult to JSON using Gson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gson, spring-validator

Environment:
  Spring boot- 1.2.3
**Issue** :

When `BindingResult` is added as next argument to `@Valid` argument for controller method like below, keep on getting  `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void createEmployee(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @RequestBody Employee employee, BindingResult result){
    logger.debug("Creating Employee [" + employee.getForename() + " " + employee.getSurname() + "]");
}
```

If `BindingResult` method argument is removed, it works fine.
***Update start***
Found the issue, `StackOverflowError` occurred while converting `BindingResult` instance to `JSON` using below code:

```
//log all method arguments   
com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(bindingResultArgFromControllerMethod);
```

Framework code uses `Gson` to convert method arguments to `JSON` for logging.

Is there way to avoid/handle this exception?
***Update end***

**Relevant Stack trace :**

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
//Repeatattive block start 
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
//Repeatattive block end 
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:155)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:106)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with that refreshed knowledge. At least at the code for your `Employee` object.

Comment: Following link has some valid points.Please go through it.

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-valid-requestbody

Comment: return type need to be changed according to this sample. public ResponseEntity create(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

Comment: ` @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleMethodArgumentNotValidException( MethodArgumentNotValidException error ) {
   return parseErrors(error.getBindingResult());
}`

Comment: @Sanka updated question after finding root cause of the exception

Comment: Can you show the important parts of the `StackOverflowError`? I.e. where does it start, and what's the repeating part. Another question: what's the type of `bindingResultArgFromControllerMethod` ? Can you show that class too?

Comment: @TamasRev added relevant stack trace. `bindingResultArgFromControllerMethod` is of type `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult`. You can replicate it using `com.google.gson.Gson  gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
        gson.toJson(bindingResult);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API docs of [BindingResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html), this is only a ***holder*** of the data that the user entered to the browser. Moreover, the implementation of BindingResult can contain all sort of references to other helper objects. Based on the stack trace, there's a circular reference on the current implementation of `BindingResult`.

I think you want to jsonify the data the user entered. Then all you need to do is to jsonify the `target` of the `BindingResult`:

```
com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(bindingResultArgFromControllerMethod.getTarget());
```

This `target` is, according to the [method docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html#getTarget()): *the wrapped target object, which may be a bean, an object with public fields, a Map - depending on the concrete binding strategy*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it did helped :)